# Not able to add IEEETran document class to Lyx (renfiguration failed)

Tags: lyx, miktex

I am using miktex 20.10 and lyx 2.3 on windows 10 and having a hard time configuring everything. I had everything installed and working properly but it stopped for some reason.

Problem: I am not able to reconfigure lyx in order to add any other document class, it sometimes says "python file configure.py did not finish" and sometimes says "Reconfiguration failed, Lyx may not work properly".

Changes from last time when everything was working fine:

1. I don't have python installed on my system, I had to remove it for some other program so, do I need to install python?
2. I installed adobe reader, it wasn't installed previously and I read  somewhere that it can cause a problem (although I don't think so)

Comment: The configure script definitely needs to run with Python. I thought that LyX shipped Python with it on Windows. If you removed that then it could cause problems. Are you using the latest, LyX version, 2.3.5.2?

Comment: Yes I am using the version 2.3.5.2, it does ship with python but for some reason there are errors while reconfiguration so, instead using texlive, it's problem free.

Comment: Glad it works now for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was with Miktex, I installed Tex Live instead of Miktex (it took 4 hours to install but it works without problems).